# How to remove another debugger so that Visual Studio can debug script

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vbscript

So I messed up and installed a crappy scripting program to debug VBscript before I realized that it could be done with VS.

So now, despite uninstalling the other debugger, I receive the following error message:
"another debugger has registered itself as the Just-In-Time debugger" and will not allow me to enable script debugging in VS.

So looking into the issue it seems that the error is in the windows register somewhere but despite me trying a few things I have not found a way to fix this. I have tried to do the VS repair a few times after making Reg changes with no luck.

I feeling like this should be a easy thing but can't seems to find the answer anywhere, help if you can.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Not sure this is really a programming problem, have you tried [su]?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger?view=vs-2019#disable-just-in-time-debugging-from-the-windows-registry).

Basically you have to delete the following registry keys (if present):

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger`

It worked in my case, I just had to restart VS(2019)

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely related to the fact the debugger is still registered but the files no longer exist because the program has been uninstalled.

Looking at the [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2019):

> Another debugger has registered itself as the Just-In-Time debugger. To repair, enable Just-In-Time debugging or run Visual Studio repair.

I would suggest the best option would be to uninstall Visual Studio completely then perform a clean install. If this seems drastic, you could always go for the Visual Studio repair option first but this might not sever the connection to the now uninstalled debugger.

Comment: Fwiw, I tried this (with a painful re-install of MSVC, as the Repair option completely wrecked my Python setup). It did not remove the message ...

Comment: @DS_London sorry to hear this, if that didn’t work the problem is likely the OS which installing clean can be painful process but not sure what other options you have.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I did re-install some elements in rather a scatter-gun approach and the issue went away: sorry to not be more precise!